# JMockit: Mocking an empty interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

```
public interface Connection extends Session {}
```

I need to mock the interface which using one of the methods in the Session class.

```
    new MockUp<Connection>() {
        @Mock ObjectInfo thisMethod(ReturnObject object) {
            return expectedObject;
        }
    };
```

thisMethod doesnt gets called during the MockUp.

How do i go about mocking the Connection interface in this case?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#interfaces).

Comment: You should use MockUp API similar as your examle. See https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-jmockit/wiki/JMockit-Quick-Tutorial-(Cheat-sheet)    //// - > Mocking methods,

Mock an interface and override/mock methods